# What is the execution order of a query with sub queries?

Tags: t-sql

Consider this query

```
select * 
from documents d
where exists (select 1 as [1]
              from (
                    select *
                    from ( 
                        select * 
                        from ProductMediaDocuments 
                        where d.id = MediaDocuments_Id
                        ) as [dummy1] 
                    ) as [s2]
                    where exists( 
                                select *
                                from ProductSkus psk
                                where psk.Product_Id = s2.MediaProducts_Id
                                )
              )
```

Could someone tell me how this is being processed by SQL Server? When statements appears in parentheses, this means it will execute first. But does this also apply for the above statement? In this case I don't think so, because the sub queries needs values of outer queries. So, how does this works under the hood?

Comment: why not post an execution plan, and remove all doubt?

Comment: does this code even run?  It looks to me like you would get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's completely up to the database engine.

Since SQL is a declarative language, you specify *WHAT* you want, but the *HOW* part is up to the DB Engine and it really depends on many factors like indexes presence, type, fragmentation; row cardinality, statistics.

That's just to mention few, because the list can goes on.

Of course you can look to the execution plan but the point is that you can't know *HOW* it will be executed just reading the query.

Comment: you should point out that every SQL server product allows you to find out what it does via a utility that will show you the execution plan.

Comment: @Hogan And you should be aware the execution plan can change over time.

Comment: Correct.  You can have a query that runs for years and does not return or touch bad data and suddenly fails because of a new execution plan (based on size, statistics, or whatever SQL wants to).  For example a string that will not convert to Date and is not part of the results but causes the query to fail on day.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code a bit.

```
SELECT * 
FROM documents d
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT 1
                FROM ProductMediaDocuments s2
                WHERE d.id = MediaDocuments_Id
                AND EXISTS  ( 
                                SELECT *
                                FROM ProductSkus psk
                                WHERE psk.Product_Id = s2.MediaProducts_Id
                            )
              )
```

Comment: this is ok, but I think using inner joins (like my answer) is even clearer.

Comment: Yes I totally agree inner joins are clearer, but the OP uses exists. Exists can perform better in some case, but also what if there are multiple matches with your joins. Then your query will return duplicate values.

Comment: As I'm sure you know the DISTINCT keyword can be used to solve that issue :)

Comment: You are so right. I'll be honest I wouldn't know which would perform better, but this is kind of why we have this forum. So the OP can get different solutions and choose which works best for them. My point on duplicates was simply that you would create duplicates and then only grab certain ones which to me sounds like more work than necessary.

Comment: It should be the case that the performance would be the same (since the queries are functionally the same), HOWEVER, in my experience SQL Server does a better job of optimizing JOINS and DB2 does a better job of optimizing EXISTS

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan will tell you what the engine actually does.  That is, the physical processing order.  AFAIK, the query planner will rewrite your query if it finds a better way to express it to itself or the engine.  If your question is, "Why is my query not working the way I think it should." then that is where you should start.

The doc says the [*logical* processing order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) is:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

It also has this note:

> The [preceding] steps show the logical processing order, or binding order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely, because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as the ORDER BY clause. Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.

`FROM` would include inline views (subqueries) or CTE aliases.  Each time it finds a subquery, it should start over from the beginning and evaluate that query.

Comment: Logical is not the same as physical

Comment: @Blam I didn't say they were.  The question doesn't specify either, so I provided both answers.

Comment: "Being processed by SQL Server" is physical in my book.

Comment: @Blam Given that query planner and query engine together will process a query both logically and physically, I would disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is clearer don't you??

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM documents d
JOIN ProductMediaDocuments s2 ON d.id = MediaDocuments_Id
JOIN ProductSkus psk ON psk.Product_Id = s2.MediaProducts_Id
```